# What on earth is she saying to me?

Tags: pattern

Today, I wanted to ask my crush out to eat. So, I told her this(Note that my language is usually informal. So the language is VERY slang):

> *Nigerió, only friend. Can you go to canteen with me? Needing to kill some time there. I understand I like you which I am sorry for. Don't worry, we **omnonon even if you owe me money. Let this be my treat. I'll take whatever you want. Anyway, let's eat now.

And then, my crush just told me (took her 2 minutes before telling me this):

> Well... AABCEHMUH and the last one is for YOU. The beginnings count, but not the beginning sequence.

And then, she just walk away...

Does anyone know why she just said those alien letters? I'm very scared that she just talked Alien to me.

*Nigerió means hello in our own created language.
**omnonon is just a literally transcript to words for the action of eating something.

By the way, this happened in real life.

Edit: I know the answer. Don't worry.

**Hint 1:**

> Originally when she replied to me, I took sooo long to notice. Infact, I had to go back home and solve this myself. One thing unbelievable is, she manage to think these letters just within 2 minutes! I mean, just 2 minutes did she manage to think something so creative. In the end... (*not revealing ending. That's another hint*). I would believe this story and solution if this isn't real life. But since this is real life.. well.. yeah. Already happened.

**Hint 2:**

> I was mad (and surprised with unbelievability) after I solved this puzzle.

Comment: Well to be fair, U = YOU, so that might be part of it...

Comment: @greenturtle3141 You seem to have solved it. If not, that is a clever comment.

Comment: Is it BC=Busy? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot nah.

Comment: Is Nigerió word of any use to solve this?

Comment: @Techidiot I'm not gonna be able to answer this one. I mean, it doesn't take 1 word of a random language to solve this. Just know that you have to solve from the pattern AABCEHMUH.

Comment: If your crush noticed this pattern in your transcript and thought up this reply that quickly, she is one heck of a brainy lady. Godspeed with your pursuit.

Comment: @Xenocacia yes. Thats why I got so amazed, mad and sad at the same time. Thank god I remembered what I said if not I'll never know what she is saying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I have an answer...

Your crush says the beginnings count, but not the beginning of the sequence.

> So let's discard the first letter of the fibonacci sequence, since presumably it's there just to help us identify the sequence as what it is.
>  That leaves 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34.

OP says in a comment, "There is GOT to be a reason why it stops at 'H'."

> It's of interest that the speaker's message is 51 words long; the next sequence value, 55, would be past the end of the message. That hints at using the fibonacci values as indices into that message.
>  That gives us "**N**igerio, **o**nly **f**riend. **Y**ou **c**anteen **k**ill **y**ou **o**we."

Clearly nonsense, but again, the beginnings count.
Your crush also said the last one is for YOU.

> Let's then take the first letter of each word, and add a "last one" of YOU→U:
>  **NOFYCKYOU**

She apparently *really* didn't want to go to lunch with you.

Comment: You can replace FYCK with "F*CK" :D Lol what was that anyway.  :D Op messed it up I guess.

Comment: I wondered. ;)  Interesting puzzle, made me think a bit.

Comment: And then it hit to my head of sudden realisation of how genius and how burned I felt the fact that she manage to think in 2 minutes already noticing the words I spoke that magically is in fibonacci by accident. I swear. By accident. And by the way, the **Y**ou is supposed to be U because I was speaking. I was transcripting to a bit proper English to make it less obvious. Note that is is a speech and I believe in modern days, we love to message people with "u" rather than "You".

Comment: @Rubio well done though.

Comment: @Rubio and then I was selective for the second You. And I supposed she meant a 'Y'.

Comment: Yeah, the use of "Y" in one case and "U" in another was what led me to just stick with the literal decoding and let people get the intended meaning without me having to post Naughty Words™.  The inference that "You" there could be "U" is simple and obvious, so I left it unsaid.

Answer (score 2):

If you take A = 1, B = 2, etc., then the sequence of letters are the Fibonacci sequence modulo 26.

```
A A B C E H M  U  H  ?  ?  ?    ...
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144  ...
```

So the next few letters are S, K, and N. Not sure if that has anything to do with the question itself, though, which doesn't ask for a sequence.

Comment: There is GOT to be a reason why it stops at 'H' :P.

Comment: 34 is for "YOU"? Are we looking for the part of the sequence that says "YOU"?

Comment: Nah. 34 isn't for me (Not close). I suggest u imagine this as a fantasy puzzle even if this happened in real life. She is just too observant.